# MobileFirst 7.1.0 Android FCM Push Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

We have developed a hybrid application using MobileFirst 7.1.0 and are looking to implement push notifications.  With the recent changes regarding GCM to FCM, I'm wondering if it would be possible to add the project to FCM and use the API Key and Sender ID?  I have seen the documentation has been updated for MobileFirst 8.0 and wondering if the same will work on 7.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation has indeed did not yet get updated for 7.1, but it is the same as for 8.0 (the part of registering the project in FCM Console and obtaining the key and senderId), so you can follow the same instructions.

1. Visit the Firebase Console.
2. Create a new project and provide a project name.
3. Click on the Settings “cog wheel” icon and select Project settings.
4. Click the Cloud Messaging tab to generate a Server API Key and a Sender ID and click Save.

Comment: Thank you Idan!  We will follow the same instructions.

Comment: Hi @JeffNorton did you managed to have FCM working with MFP 7? thanks

Comment: @TobiaZambon - Yes, we were able to use the API Key and Sender ID from FCM in our MobileFirst 7.1 application.

Comment: How did you handle the GCM alert telling you GCM is not config correcly?

Comment: I mean, I've already changed the push sender keys to FCM, delete all in manifest but still appears this shit dialog